# initializationFailTimeout property in HikariCP

Tags: spring-boot, database-connection, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

From Github:

> Any positive number is taken to be the number of milliseconds to
> attempt to acquire an initial connection; the application thread will
> be blocked during this period. Default: 1

I understand when using default value if connection is not obtained within 1 sec then error will be thrown .I am planning to set the value as 1000 ms as sometimes I am getting the error as

> "hikaripool$poolinitializationexception"

when starting the spring boot Java 8 app. Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly it wait for connection `connectTimeout` + `initializationFailTimeout` , from [github](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#infrequently-used):

> This timeout is applied after the `connectionTimeout` period

Which is by default half a minute

> Default: 30000 (30 seconds)

You can enter `-1` value to allow pool to start without failing

> A value less than zero will bypass any initial connection attempt, and the pool will start immediately while trying to obtain connections in the background

Comment: Ok got it so do you suggent increse initializationFailTimeout to 30 seconds.Since i have 2 HIKARI CP and sometimes my app doesnt start because of error`"hikaripool$poolinitializationexception"`

Comment: @helloworld need to check why exception is thrown for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166458/com-zaxxer-hikari-pool-poolinitializationexception-exception-during-pool-initia

Comment: @helloworld also you can put negative number `A value less than zero will bypass any initial connection attempt, and the pool will start immediately while trying to obtain connections in the background`

Comment: i didnt get any erro .Just `NULL`  in the stack trace.It occurs while deploying on cloud that too sometimes

Comment: @helloworld try setting `initializationFailTimeout` with `-1`

Comment: No .I don't want to start my app without obtaining  DB connection. I have increased initializationFailTimeout value.It works so far !